# How to set OffscreenPageLimit in Xamarin Forms with Shell?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin Forms 4.0 with Shell. I have Tabbed pages by using ShellSection.

How do I set the OffScreenPageLimit in Android to be 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it via the platform specific `On<T>` method:

```
On<Android>().SetOffscreenPageLimit(numberOfPagesToCache);
```

re: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/e8cc89bfc8f210267f7ebbe133b4cf84c9ddef20/Xamarin.Forms.Controls/GalleryPages/PlatformSpecificsGalleries/TabbedPageAndroid.cs#L21

Comment: Where would I set this if I'm using Shell? I'm not directly creating a TabbedPage

Comment: Apply it in the .ctor of your TabbedPage implementation if that is what you are using as the shell content, otherwise `SetOffscreenPageLimit` works in bindable objects, so you can apply via your `ShellItem` (assuming you are using the default template)

Comment: I have a `ShellItem` with several `ShellSection`s in it(bottom tabs), and one of those bottom tabs has 5 'ShellContent''s inside, turning that `ShellSection` into a `TabbedPage`. So I guess I would need to apply it to that `ShellSection`.
I'm not familiar with bindable objects to understand how to set it. Would you mind giving an example? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Kyle Let me check with the latest Forms 4.0pre as my original shell code does not work at all with the "latest" shell interfaces, even Microsoft's published samples do not work with the latest Forms 4.0pre code. (You might get a faster answer on their gitter: https://gitter.im/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms)